# Getting data from MySQL to android and displaying as list under "App List" Tab?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-c2dm

I am a noob in android dev.. I have couple of questions..

1...I have database created in localhost in MySQL server. Table of all the "States".

Q2...I created PHP script to connect to the database, and getting the list from the database.. ...I need to convert this to Json file/data to be read in android...????

Q3...I created android project with tab views for list tab, getting & saving details tab, settings tab.. where details are settings tab are form view elements and need to write them back in json n send them to MySql database. how do i do that.. in php or android or both...?????

Q4.. When the user first installs the app and runs it, my app should send to the server the mobile registration id... how do it do that..????? 
 I tried C2DM, but no luck.. I am testing everything in the emulator first..

I am so stuck in these issues.. i have created more than 10 projects for each individual feature with the help of forums and blogs and google developer forums .. and yet dint succeed in anything.. 
PLZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.... HELPPPPPPPPP!!!!!!!!!!!!?????

Thanks in adv.. 
Su

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. It is typical to use the `json_encode()` function to output a PHP array as a JSON object. This can be consumed by your android application by an AJAX call, passing in the URL to your PHP script.

Q2. Prepare an array of what you want to output as normal and then call `json_encode()` on it.

Q3. Look through the Android documentation and find a JSON encoding function. To 'send it to MySQL' you will need to pass the JSON output through an HTTP POST request to your PHP script that can validate the data and submit it to the database.

Comment: Ok .. I will add the json_encode() to the php file and also through ajax call and test it.. I have one more question.. I added 3 tabs in the main.xml... one is list, 2 are forms.. now how do i add elements to each tabs,..??? for the first one I have List view.. where do i add the form view in the other tabs.. ??? I am confused on how to do that in the main.xml..

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost">
    <LinearLayout>
        <TabWidget />
        <FrameLayout
            <ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
            </ListView>